# SSIS Aggregate transformation

Tags: ssis

I am working on a very large SSIS package with many transformations.

I need to do an AGGREGATE that groups a field and also counts the field,

the problem that I am having is the AGGREGATE is coming from a MULTICAST.  I tried doing a SORT from the MULTICAST then an AGGREGATE but I lose all of the other columns and I need them.

I tried adding another SORT coming from the MULTICAST so that I can have all of the columns and have all transformations going into a MERGE but the package gets hung up on the SORT coming from the MULTICAST.

MULTICAST is also being routed into a CONDITIONAL SPLIT, in which one of the splits will have an AGGREGATE that groups a field and also counts the field and will go into the above MERGE.

.
[image: img]

`SORT 1` is sorting by CUSTOMER ID and `SORT 2` is sorting by CUSTOMER ID_SYSTEM.

`Aggregate 1` groups CUSTOMER_ID and count distinct CUSTOMER_ID and `Aggregate 2` groups CUSTOMER ID_SYSTEM and count distinct CUSTOMER_ID SYSTEM.

Basically  what I am trying to accomplish by doing the AGGREGATE is if COUNTS from the first AGGREGATE equal the COUNTS from the second AGGREGATE then those rows will go down a separate path than those rows in which the COUNTS  don’t match.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this without the package taking a long time to process, right now the package does not get past the SORTS.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to handle this is to send it to a destination table with covering index(es) at the point of the multicast, and then do the aggregating and comparison logic in a stored procedure.  Then if more dataflow processing is needed, start a new dataflow with that table as the source.

Sorting and aggregating in an SSIS dataflow is always going to be slow and not recommended for lots of rows.   Nothing you can do about it but avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know of an SSIS function that will allow for counting the grouped fields and if the counts of two fields do not equal each other then all of those rows will be routed to a separate destination.?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that built into SSIS.